# get an element out of a string python

Tags: python

I am trying to use line.strip() and line.split() to get an element out of a file, but this always gives me a list of string, does line.split() always return a string? how can I just get a list of elements instead of a list of 'elements'?

```
    myfile = open('myfile.txt','r')
    for line in myfile:
            line_strip = line.strip()
            myline = line_strip.split(' ')
    print(myline)
```

So my code gives me ['hello','hi']
I want to get a list out of the file look likes[hello,hi]

```
    [2.856,9.678,6.001] 6 Mary
    [8.923,3.125,0.588] 7 Louis
    [7.122,9.023,4,421] 16 Ariel
```

so when I try

```
    list = []
    list.append((mylist[0][0],mylist[0][1]))
```

I actually want a list = [(2.856,9.678),(8.923,3.123),(7.122,9.023)]
but it seems this mylist[0][0] refers to '[' in my file

Comment: Please show your code as a [mcve] and your input and expected output.

Comment: `line.split()` always returns a string. `list.split()` always returns a list. Your question is somewhat unclear. Perhaps you could post a short program that demonstrates your question. See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: @Robᵩ Shouldn't `line.split()` return a list (assuming space delimited columns)?

Comment: I used line.split() for a csv file, it gives me a [hello,hi], but for a text file, it prints a list of string, so I am now a bit confused, if line.split() always gives a list of strings, why did i get a list of elements for the csv file?

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with `['hello','hi']`. Why do you think the quotes should not be there?

Comment: I have numbers in my file, and I used list =[] list.append(float(myline[0]), but because it gives me a list of string, I cannot convert this into a float

Comment: `float('2.0')` works fine... If `myline` is a string, then `myline[0]` is only the first character. You can't convert a non number to a float

Comment: I think because I have a list of numbers in my file, so when I use line.split(), it gives a nested list, and when I try to append the first element, it is actually a'[',  do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: If you have a mixed list of numbers and non-numbers and want to convert that list, you either need to use `try / except` or separate out the number like strings before using `int` or `float` on them. Please update your answer with SPECIFIC input and desired output. If you are using `.split(',')` is this a CSV file? If so, you may want to use the CSV module.

Comment: *it is actually a'['*... @joe Please show your actual code (and the file content)

Comment: @dawg  I am actually reading a text file, I used .split('  '). My file has each line looks like this: [2.856,9.678,6.001]   2   mary                                             and my code is as above, I want to append 2.856 to my list: list = [], but I do not want '2.856', I tried to use list.append(float(myline[0][0])), but it returns '['

Comment: Do you actually have the string `[2.856,9.678,6.001]` in the file or do you have `2.856,9.678,6.001`? Once again -- your answers will be way better if you put an actual example of the file (a line or two) into your question.

Comment: @dawg   the first one

Comment: Only that or more? Put an example line in the question. I will reopen if it is different that the one marked as a duplicate.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Of course you are right. I meant that to say that `.strip()` returns a string, but got my wires crossed somehow. *Mea culpa*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you posted, use a regex:

```
>>> s="[2.856,9.678,6.001] 6 Mary"
>>> import re
>>> [float(e) for e in re.search(r'\[([^\]]+)',s).group(1).split(',')]
[2.856, 9.678, 6.001]
```

For all the lines you posted (and this would be similar to a file) you might do:

```
>>> txt="""\
...     [2.856,9.678,6.001] 6 Mary
...     [8.923,3.125,0.588] 7 Louis
...     [7.122,9.023,4,421] 16 Ariel"""
>>> for line in txt.splitlines():
...    print [float(e) for e in re.search(r'\[([^\]]+)',line).group(1).split(',')]
... 
[2.856, 9.678, 6.001]
[8.923, 3.125, 0.588]
[7.122, 9.023, 4.0, 421.0]
```

You would need to add error code to that (if the match fails for instance) but this is the core of what you are looking for.

---

BTW: Don't use `list` as a variable name. You will overwrite the `list` function and have confusing errors in the future...

Answer (score 1):

```
my_string = 'hello'
my_list = list(my_string) # ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
my_new_string = ''.join(my_list) # 'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this

```
>>> print("[{}]".format(", ".join(data)))
[1, 2, 3]
```

To address your question, though

> this always gives me a list of string,

Right. As `str.split()` should do.

> does line.split() always return a string?

Assuming `type(line) == str`, then no, it returns a list of string elements from the split line.

> how can I just get a list of `elements` instead of a list of `'elements'`?

Your "elements" are strings. The `'` marks are only Python's **`repr`** of a `str` type.

For example...

```
print('4') # 4
print(repr('4')) # '4'

line = "1,2,3"
data = line.split(",")
print(data)  # ['1', '2', '3']
```

You can cast to a different data-type as you wish

```
print([float(x) for x in data]) # [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.split()` returns a **list** of strings.

For example:

`my_string = 'hello hi'`
`my_string.split(' ')` is equal to `['hello', 'hi']`

To put a list of strings, like `['hello', 'hi]` back together, use **join**.

For example, `' '.join(['hello', 'hi'])` is equal to `'hello hi'`. The `' '` specifies to put a space between all the elements in the list that you are joining.

Comment: thx, do you know how can I just get ([hello, hi]) instead of strings

Comment: @joe what do you mean? why are there parentheses around the list?

Comment: sorry, it should be [hello,hi], without the parentheses